# How to obtain sequence of submodules from a pytorch module?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

For a pytorch [module](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Module.html), I suppose I could use `.named_children`, `.named_modules`, etc. to obtain a list of the submodules. However, I suppose the list is not given in order, right? An example:

```
In [19]: import transformers

In [20]: model = transformers.DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilb
    ...: ert-base-cased')

In [21]: [name for name, _ in model.named_children()]
Out[21]: ['distilbert', 'pre_classifier', 'classifier', 'dropout']
```

The order of `.named_children()` in the above model is given as distilbert, pre_classifier, classifier, and dropout. However, if you examine the [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/9931f817b75ecb2c8bb08b6e9d4cbec4b0933935/src/transformers/modeling_distilbert.py#L641), it is evident that `dropout` happens before `classifier`. So how do I get the order of these submodules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pytorch, the results of `print(model)` or `.named_children()`, etc are listed based on the order they are declared in `__init__` of the model's class e.g.

**Case 1**

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.6)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

model = Model()
print(model)
[name for name, _ in model.named_children()]
# output
['conv1', 'conv2', 'fc1', 'fc2', 'conv2_drop']
```

**Case 2**

Changed order of `fc1` and `fc2` layers in constructor.

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.6)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

model = Model()
print(model)
[name for name, _ in model.named_children()]
# output
['conv1', 'conv2', 'fc2', 'fc1', 'conv2_drop']
```

---

That's why `classifier` is printed before `dropout` as it's declared so in constructor:

```py
class DistilBertForSequenceClassification(DistilBertPreTrainedModel):
        ...
        self.distilbert = DistilBertModel(config)
        self.pre_classifier = nn.Linear(config.dim, config.dim)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.dim, config.num_labels)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.seq_classif_dropout)
```

---

Nevertheless, you can play with model's submodules using `.modules()`, etc. but they'll be listed only in the order they are declared in `__init__`. If you only want to print structure based on `forward` method, you may try using [pytorch-summary](https://github.com/Fangyh09/pytorch-summary).

Comment: It seems the flow is not explicitly saved in the module object, except in the form of the method `.forward`. I suppose if I want the flow I can examine the `.forward` method. In ipython, running `model.forward??` does the trick.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably have to use hooks or something, as they did in pytorch-summary package.