# How to visulaize or print the output from each layer of PyTorch saved model specifically for vision_transformer?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

**What I have done?**

I have trained a ViT using PyTorch `from torchvision.models import vision_transformer as vits` specifically `model = vits.vit_b_16(pretrained=False, num_classes=10).to(device)` and saved the whole model using `torch.save(model, "vit_mnist_model.pth")` in the separate python file i have loaded the model and also test it on single image from the dataset it is working fine.

**What I want to do?**

As transformer use the attention mechanism. I want to visualize the patches self attention is focusing most in the prediction of the image. To do that i want to pass the same image to the ViT and get the output from the each encoder block. Further, my plan is to visualize these patches that are output from from each block using matplot.

**Code I am using till now**

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
from torchsummary import summary

# Set device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Load MNIST test dataset and apply transformations
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=3),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

# Create data loader
batch_size = 1  # Set batch size to 1 to process one image at a time
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)


# Load the saved model state dictionary
model =torch.load('vit_mnist_model.pth')

# Set the model in evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Get a single image from the test data at position 5
index = 5
image, label = test_dataset[index]
image = image.unsqueeze(0).to(device)  # Add a batch dimension and move to the device

# Print the summary of the model
summary(model, input_size=(3, 224, 224), print_summary=True)

print(image.shape)

for name, module in model.named_modules():
    print(name)

# Pass the image through the model up to the 'encoder_layer_11'
output = image
for name, module in model.named_children():
    output = module(output)
    if name == 'encoder':
        for encoder_name, encoder_module in module.named_children():
            output = encoder_module(output)
            if encoder_name == 'layer11':
                encoder_layer_output = output
                break

print(f"Output shape of 'encoder_layer_11': {encoder_layer_output.shape}")
print(encoder_layer_output)
```

**Error I am getting**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blggpu2/Projects/VisionTransformer/visualize_vit.py", line 54, in <module>
    output = module(output)
  File "/home/blggpu2/anaconda3/envs/pyTorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blggpu2/anaconda3/envs/pyTorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/models/vision_transformer.py", line 155, in forward
    torch._assert(input.dim() == 3, f"Expected (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_dim) got {input.shape}")
  File "/home/blggpu2/anaconda3/envs/pyTorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 853, in _assert
    assert condition, message
AssertionError: Expected (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_dim) got torch.Size([1, 768, 14, 14])
```

I don't understand why it is giving an error when I pass the image using the for loop. I am just passing the image to the input layer and whatever it giving output I am transferring that output to the next layer.

**Update**

I used the below code to get the output for specific layers. However, it is a bit confusing, first of all, according to my knowledge transformer breaks the image into patches but when I return the output of the 'conv_proj' it returns [1, 768, 14, 14] meaning there are 768 patches of size 14 x 14. But when I plot them they show the whole 768 images not just a patch. Further 'encoder.layers.encoder_layer_11' returns [1, 197, 768] which doesn't make any sense to me as it cant be plotted.

```
for name, module in model.named_modules():
    print(name)
return_nodes = {
    
    "conv_proj": "layer1",
    "encoder.layers.encoder_layer_11": "layer2",
   

}
model2 = create_feature_extractor(model, return_nodes=return_nodes)
intermediate_outputs = model2(image)


print(intermediate_outputs['layer1'].shape)
print(intermediate_outputs['layer2'].shape)

out1= intermediate_outputs['layer1'][0,0,:,:]
normalized_output = out1.cpu().detach().numpy()

plt.imshow(normalized_output, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

**Output**

```
torch.Size([1, 768, 14, 14])
torch.Size([1, 197, 768])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381286/how-to-obtain-sequence-of-submodules-from-a-pytorch-module), the order of the elements in `model.named_children()` is given by the order of appearance in the `__init__` method of the model, which means that without access to this method, the order of appearance of the different layers is not guaranteed.

Moreover, even if you are certain that modules will appear in the correct order, your loop will still probably cause an error, because some parts of the model will be used twice. In your loop, when the module named `encoder` appears, the current value of `output` is processed and saved to the same variable with `output = encoder(output)`. After, children layers of the encoder are applied to the current value of `output`, which have already been processed by the encoder. The effect of that will be, in the best case if the shapes and layers are not compatible, to raise an error like you got, and in the worst case if shapes and layers are compatible, to give you an answer as a tensor, but which would not be what you wanted, since the data would have gone through the encoder once and then through some parts of the encoder again, resulting on uninterpretable results.

#### Update

First, about the `conv_proj` output :

This is the opposite, you have 14*14=196 patches, each of which being summarized by a 768-sized representation. This representation is not really vizualizable, since each feature could be independant from the other. If you want something that can be seen as an image, you could check the kernel of the convolution layer. This will give you a [k, k, n] tensor, with k being the kernel size of the convolution, and n the number of filters (likely to be 768, unless there are other layers after the convolutions). For interpretation, you could visualize each [k, k] array as "How important is each pixel for this filter". Values can be positive or negative, depending on whether the pixel has a positive or negative effect on this filter.

Then about the transformer layer :

The dimension you get is [B, T, N], where B is batch size (1 in your case), T is some kind of "time" dimension and N is the size of the representation. Since an image does not have a time dimension, one is constructed by defining an order between the patches, so you find again the 196 patches you already had from the convolution layer, with one patch added by the transformer layer, which gives the T=196 dimension. Finally N is the size of the embedding, which is kept at 768. As for the previous one, this representation is not really meant to be visualized, something that can be interesting to watch is the attention maps from the Transformer layers. It is a [T,T,H]-sized tensor, where T is still the "time" dimension (197) and H is the number of heads in this layer. Each of these T*T tensors are describing the importance of each patch relatively to the other to construct the output of the layer, and so for each attention head you have. You can find some details in [this link from Pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html), the output is named `attn_output_weights` and you might have to tweak a bit your implementation to get these.

Comment: I added a few things about visualization of the layers parameters

Comment: it was really helpful I don't realize we can get `attn_output_weights` along with `attn_output` by using `attn_output, attn_output_weights = multihead_attn(query, key, value)`. Further, I will try to figure out a way to visualize these attention maps and update it soon.